# Spring webflux WebClient post a file to a client

Tags: java, aws-lambda, spring-webflux

I'm trying to figure out how to write a method to simply send a file from a webflux controller to a 'regular' controller.

I'm constantly getting a common error back, but nothing I've tried has resolved it.

The method I'm sending the file from:

```
@GetMapping("process")
public Flux<String> process() throws MalformedURLException {
    final UrlResource resource = new UrlResource("file:/tmp/document.pdf");

    MultiValueMap<String, UrlResource> data = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    data.add("file", resource);

    return webClient.post()
            .uri(LAMBDA_ENDPOINT)
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(data))
            .exchange()
            .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class))
            .flux();
}
```

I'm consuming it in a AWS Lambda with the following endpoint:

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/input", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<?>> input(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(file.getBytes());

        //[..]

        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

But I'm constantly just getting:

```
{  
   "timestamp":1549395273838,
   "status":400,
   "error":"Bad Request",
   "message":"Required request part 'file' is not present",
   "path":"/detect-face"
}
```

back from the lambda;

Have I just setup the sending of the file incorrectly, Or do I need to configure something on the API Gateway to allow the request parameters in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a interesting one for me. As I'm using a lambda function on the receiving end, and making use of `aws-serverless-java-container-spring` I actually had to declare the `MultipartResolver` manually.

The code in my question worked correctly once I added

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
}
```

to my configuration.

Maybe someone will stumble on this and find it useful.

Comment: Does your solution work fine for large file upload ?